# how to get total records from left table and matched records form right table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have 2 table. how to get total records from left table and matched records form right table in mysql? i am using below query but it will get only matched records from two tables.

```
SELECT post_id,COUNT(post_id) as pid,hostel_id,ht.user_id,hostel_name,
       hostel_type,hostel_district,hostel_area,post_date,hostel_rent,hostel_respond,
       h_contact_num,created_date,h_food_type
FROM hostels ht
left join histroy hr
    ON ht.hostel_id =hr.post_id
WHERE ht.hostel_district=$city_code AND
      ht.status='1' AND
      hr.post_type='Hostel'
GROUP BY hr.post_id
ORDER by pid DESC
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data to illustrate what you want here?  Your ask is unclear to me in the context of a `GROUP BY` query.

Comment: You have to add all columns except `COUNT(post_id) as pid` in your group by clause.

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453809/how-to-use-mysql-found-rows-in-php) will help you

Answer (score 1):

If you want the number of *total* records per group, then just `COUNT(*)`.  If you want the number of records from the `histroy` table which matched to something in the `hostels` table, then your current use of `COUNT(post_id)` should already be doing this.  If you want the number of records in `hostels` which did *not* match to anything in `histroy`, then you can use this:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN post_id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_hostels_no_match
```

Comment: Is that the same as "doesn't match anything" or is that just "doesn't match something"

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution more an illustrated comment.
A left (outer) join is the correct way to get everything from hostels but aggregate functions ignore null values. for example given

```
drop table if exists t;

create table t (id int, val int);
insert into t values
(1,1),(2,null),(3,3);
```

this query

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select count(val) nonnullcount
    -> from t;
```

returns

```
+--------------+
| nonnullcount |
+--------------+
|            2 |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you want the count to include all entries then you should cater for the null values.